# Laravel 5.2 Authentication via API

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am developing a RESTful API with Laravel 5.2. In the token guard located at `\Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard\TokenGuard.php` on line 46 the column name for the token is defined as `api_token`:

```
$this->storageKey = 'api_token';
```

I want to change this column name to something else, for example `api_key`.

How can I do this? I do not want to modify the core `TokenGuard.php` file.

Comment: why do you want to change that? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: in my table, the name of the column is 'api_key'. Therefore, I want laravel to look for 'api_key' column and not 'api_token' column when searching for the token.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The built in `TokenGuard` does not have a way to modify the `storageKey` field. Therefore, you will need to create your own `Guard` class that sets the field, and tell `Auth` to use your `Guard` class.

First, start by creating a new `Guard` class that extends the base `TokenGuard` class. In this example, it is created at `app/Services/Auth/MyTokenGuard.php`:

```
namespace App\Services\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class MyTokenGuard extends TokenGuard
{
    public function __construct(UserProvider $provider, Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct($provider, $request);
        $this->inputKey = 'api_key'; // if you want to rename this, as well
        $this->storageKey = 'api_key';
    }
}
```

Once you've created your class, you need to let `Auth` know about it. You can do this in the `boot()` method on your `AuthServiceProvider` service provider:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    Auth::extend('mytoken', function($app, $name, array $config) {
        return new \App\Services\Auth\MyTokenGuard(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']), $app['request']);
    });
}
```

And finally, you need to tell `Auth` to use your new `mytoken` guard. This is done in the `config/auth.php` config file.

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'mytoken',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @patricus, I am new to this and could not figure out how to accept. then I applied common sense and clicked on grey check mark, it became green. Thank you for elaborated answer, it helped.

Comment: @patricus how i can define api_token from another table relation with user tables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319639/how-to-change-api-token-column-in-token-guard

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to configure that.

The only way to use an other key is to create your own "Guard": [Adding Custom Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

You can extend the `TokenGuard` class and override the `__constructor` with your own column names.