# Custom Recaller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want change default cookie `remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d` to `myprefix_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d`

I find code in `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`

```
/**
 * Get the name of the cookie used to store the "recaller".
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function getRecallerName() {
   return 'remember_'.$this->name.'_'.sha1(static::class);
 }
```

How i can create custom `SessionGuard`? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since the built in `SessionGuard` does not have a way to change this, you will need to create your own `Guard` class to override the method, and tell `Auth` to use your `Guard` class. This information is also explained in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847953/laravel-5-2-authentication-via-api), which explains how to customize the `TokenGuard`.

First, start by creating a new `Guard` class that extends the base `SessionGuard` class. In your new `Guard` class, you will override the `getRecallerName()` method to return the name you want. In this example, it is created at `app/Services/Auth/MySessionGuard.php`:

```
namespace App\Services\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;

class MySessionGuard extends SessionGuard
{
    /**
     * Get the name of the cookie used to store the "recaller".
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRecallerName()
    {
        return 'myprefix_'.$this->name.'_'.sha1(static::class);
    }
}
```

Once you've created your class, you need to let `Auth` know about it. You can do this in the `boot()` method on your `AuthServiceProvider` service provider:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    Auth::extend('mysession', function($app, $name, array $config) {
        $provider = $this->createUserProvider($config['provider']);

        $guard = new \App\Services\Auth\MySessionGuard($name, $provider, $app['session.store']);        

        // When using the remember me functionality of the authentication services we
        // will need to be set the encryption instance of the guard, which allows
        // secure, encrypted cookie values to get generated for those cookies.
        if (method_exists($guard, 'setCookieJar')) {
            $guard->setCookieJar($app['cookie']);
        }
        if (method_exists($guard, 'setDispatcher')) {
            $guard->setDispatcher($app['events']);
        }
        if (method_exists($guard, 'setRequest')) {
            $guard->setRequest($app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest'));
        }

        return $guard;
    });
}
```

And finally, you need to tell `Auth` to use your new `mysession` guard. This is done in the `config/auth.php` config file.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'mysession',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Why is `sha1(static::class)` added to the name?

Comment: the only benefit i can think of adding sha1 of the class namespace + name is so you can know which class set which session variable, making it harder for clashes between different classes.

It also looks cryptic, but seems to provide little security benefit.

Comment: Tried this in Laravel 5.8 and got `Call to undefined method App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::createUserProvider()`

Comment: Looks like one has to get the provider like this: `$provider = resolve('auth')->createUserProvider($config['provider']);`