# how to change api_token column in token guard

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

**Laravel 5.5**

I want to change direction of api token that used in **TokenGaurd** so,
i created a custom guard named **CafeTokenGaurd** extends TokenGuard, i define  __construct function into it like what i want, something like this:

```
public function __construct(UserProvider $provider, Request $request) {
        parent::__construct($provider, $request);
        $this->inputKey = 'api_key'; // I want changing this part
        $this->storageKey = 'api_key';
    }
```

Now i want to define `api_key` from relation with users table like this:

```
device_user table -> token
```

i want to define specific tokens for each devices user have, and i want to set api key input and storage key to this column in pivot table between users and devices,

how i should this?!

Thanks

Comment: I have same problem too. :(

Comment: The problem is complicated if you could describe it simple It would be better help you..

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti Change name of column that token guard  use for storage key of tokens

Comment: so what happens if you change it directly? As you already mentioned that you have your own `CafeTokenGuard` class so why don't you change the name over there?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti i Can change it to another column in users table, i want to change it to another column in another table not users table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to change how the user is retrieved out of the database, you actually need to create and use a custom `UserProvider`, not a custom `Guard`. You'll only need the custom guard if you feel like renaming the input key or storage key from `api_token`.

So, you'll need a new custom `UserProvider` class that knows how to retrieve your user with the given credentials (token), and you'll need to tell `Auth` to use your new custom `UserProvider` class.

First, assuming you're still using Eloquent, start by creating a new `UserProvider` class that extends the base `EloquentUserProvider` class. In this example, it is created at `app/Services/Auth/MyEloquentUserProvider.php`. In this class, you will need to override the `retrieveByCredentials` function with the details on how to retrieve the user with the provided token.

```
namespace App\Services\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

class MyEloquentUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials)) {
            return;
        }

        // $credentials will be an array that looks like:
        // [
        //     'api_token' => 'token-value',
        // ]

        // $this->createModel() will give you a new instance of the class
        // defined as the model in the auth config for your application.

        // Your logic to find the user with the given token goes here.

        // Return found user or null if not found.
    }
}
```

Once you've created your class, you need to let `Auth` know about it. You can do this in the `boot()` method on your `AuthServiceProvider` service provider. This example will use the name "myeloquent", but you can use whatever you want (except "eloquent" and "database").

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('myeloquent', function($app, array $config) {
        return new \App\Services\Auth\MyEloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
    });
}
```

And finally, you need to tell `Auth` to use your new `myeloquent` user provider. This is done in the `config/auth.php` config file.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'myeloquent', // this is the provider name defined above
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

You can read more about adding custom user providers in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers).

Comment: so in this array [
        'api_token' => 'token-value',
         ] how i can define $user->devices instance? my api tokens are in pivot between devices and users Thats my problem

Comment: @Katerou22 The idea is that you have your 'token-value'. Now you need to look up the user that belongs to that token. I don't know your model names or relationships, but you're probably looking for something like this inside the `retrieveByCredentials()` method: `$user = $this->createModel()->newQuery()->whereHas('devices', function ($query) use ($credentials) { return $query->where('device_user.token', $credentials['api_token']); })->first();` Theoretically, this gets the user that has a related device that has a matching token.

Comment: You're awesome did you know?! (i haven't test it yet)

Comment: ,Can you check it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843469/soft-deleting-in-pivot-with-sync-method-laravel @patricus

Answer (score 21):

Since the version [Laravel 5.7.28](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v5.7.28), You can simply set up in `config/auth.php`.

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'input_key' => 'token',   // The input name to pass through
        'storage_key' => 'token', // The column name to store in database
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Laravel documentation does not mention this and it's awful

Comment: I face the same condition, I want to change api_token to token_mobile from table rb_konsumen and following your instruction, unfortunately it doesn't work. This is my guard:
```php
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'input_key' => 'token_mobile',
            'storage_key' => 'token_mobile',
            'provider' => 'rb_konsumen',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```