# Soft deleting in pivot with sync method laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I want sync some relation in User's Table and I don't want to Laravel delete the row, I want make some updates on that row (Like fill the deleted_at),
I searched so far and only solution i found is that to override sync method.

So how i can override the sync method to update the row?

Or whats another solution for this problem?

EDITED: I know the problem is with `detach` method, If i could override the `detach` It will be solved!

Thanks

Comment: Yea, Same question here...

Answer (score 2):

I think you were looking for this method.

```php
$user->your_relation()->updateExistingPivot($userid, ['deleted_at' => $date]);
```