# How to Change Default api_token API Laravel to Another Field on Another Table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to change API Guard from api_token to mobile_token, and from users table to rb_konsumen. I use Laravel 8.
I have followed instruction on:
[This Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319639/how-to-change-api-token-column-in-token-guard)

but doesn't work.
This is my app/config/auth.php

```php
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'input_key' => 'token_mobile',
            'storage_key' => 'token_mobile',
            'provider' => 'rb_konsumen',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

But when I try to authenticate, this error appears:

```php
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve by adding provider 'rb_konsumen' to config/auth.php:

```php
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'rb_konsumen' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\RbKonsumen::class,
    ],
],
```